# error in deploying a node app in azure

Tags: azure, azure-deployment

I am trying to deploy a node app into azure, while doing last step of deployment
`git push azure master`, an error occurred as below.

> fatal: unable to access 'https://lalit@wittyparrot.com@node-deploy-to-azure.scm.azurewebsites.net/node-deploy-to-azure.git/': Couldn't resolve host 'wittyparrot.com@node-deploy-to-azure.scm.azurewebsites.net'

Please help to resolove it.

Comment: Add your remote as `https://{appname}.scm.azurewebsites.net`, for example `git remote add azure https://{appname}.scm.azurewebsites.net`.

Comment: Hi...thanks...But i already added the url   C:\Users\WittyParrot\Documents\node-deploy-to-azure>git remote add azure https://node-deploy-to-azure.azurewebsites.net
fatal: remote azure already exists.

C:\Users\WittyParrot\Documents\node-deploy-to-azure>git push azure master
fatal: unable to access 'https://lalit@wittyparrot.com@node-deploy-to-azure.scm.azurewebsites.net/node-deploy-to-azure.git/': Couldn't resolve host 'wittyparrot.com@node-deploy-to-azure.scm.azurewebsites.net'

Comment: Remove the `azure` remote first with `git remote rm azure`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is like @evilSnobu has said. Use the url `https://{appname}.scm.azurewebsites.com`.

What you have met is caused by your deployment user name, as you use the format `https://{username}@{appname}.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/{appname}.git`

In your case, you set it as `lalit@wittyparrot.com`. You may have done this setting in Azure Cloud Shell and it showed no error.

But in fact, the name can only contain letters, numbers, hyphens and underscores. Otherwise your url can't be resolved correctly.
You can see the tip here.
[image: deployment credential]
Azure Cloud Shell may miss some necessary pattern check so that invalid user name causes no error to show.

Comment: Hi Jerry...git push azure master is asking authentication...when i give username and pass...it is throwing message ....C:\Users\WittyParrot\Documents\node-deploy-to-azure>git push azure master
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://lalit-wittyparrot.com@node-deploy-to-azure.scm.azurewebsites.net/node-deploy-to-azure.git/'...i didn't get which id and pass to enter..all username pass i tried..please hep..

Comment: Have you specified username and password using `az webapp deployment user set` ?

Comment: @jerry...After deployment i put the url in browser but output is not as expected...a blue screen with a message "Your app is up and running"...please suggest...url is https://node-deploy-to-azure.azurewebsites.net ..check for reference

Comment: It is `You do not have permission to view this directory or page.` right now. Depolyment succeeded, now It is related to how you build your node app, a link  [how to build node web on azure](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/laurelle/2015/12/01/how-to-deploy-a-node-js-site-into-azure-web-app-to-create-a-website/) for you to refer. If you have further question about it, you can post a new question because it's hard to offer detailed answer in comment. Besides, if my solution to your deployment is ok ,you may accept it as an answer, thanks.